# Integral of a function along fibers continuous

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Is the function
$$
W(y) = \int_{f^{-1}(\{y\})} \phi(x) \mathcal{H}^{n-m}(dx)
$$
continuous over regular values $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, for a $C^\infty$-smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$ and suitably smooth $
\phi$?

- I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226272/is-the-integral-of-a-continuous-functions-along-fibers-again-continuous) question, but there $f$ was only continuous and $y$ didn't need to be a regular value.
- Notice that by Sard's theorem $\mathcal{H}^{n-m}(fA_m)= 0 $ where $A_m$ is the set of critical points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the rank of the differential there is less than $m$.

Comment: If $y$ is a regular value, then in a neighborhood of $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ we have "product coordinates" in which $f$ looks like $f(u,v)=v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks! Is this the result of a theorem?

Comment: It is a consequence of the inverse function theorem. It’s a local normal form for submersions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, so due to the Canonical Submersion Theorem one can write the submersion as a projection. I don't see how this helps though. I understand this gives a set of local coordinates for the function $f$

Comment: So now what happens if you cover $f^{-1}(y)$ by open "rectangles" that give you the canonical submersion, take a partition of unity subordinate to that cover, and compute your integral appropriately?

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay so it would go something like this. By Inverse Function Theorem, fixed $u_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n}, v_0\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f(u_0) = v_0$ there exists a neighborhood $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ of $u_0$ and a neighborhood $V\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ of $v_0$ such that we can write the system of equations $f(u) = v$ as the graph of a smooth function $\Gamma(F) = \{(w, F(w))\,:\, w\in U\}$, where $F:U\to V$.